# Fast line drawing in OpenGL

Tags: c++, performance, opengl

I am working on a project that requires drawing a lot of data as it is acquired by an ADC...something like 50,000 lines per frame on a monitor 1600 pixels wide.  It runs great on a system with a 2007-ish Quadro FX 570, but basically can't keep up with the data on machines with Intel HD 4000 class chips.  The data load is 32 channels of 200 Hz data received in batches of 5 samples per channel 40 times per second.  So, in other words, the card only needs to achieve 40 frames per second or better.

I am using a single VBO for all 32 channels with space for 10,000 vertices each.  The VBO is essentially treated like a series of ring buffers for each channel.  When the data comes in, I decimate it based on the time scale being used.  So, basically, it tracks the min/max for each channel.  When enough data has been received for a single pixel column, it sets the next two vertices in the VBO for each channel and renders a new frame.

I use glMapBuffer() to access the data once, update all of the channels, use glUnmapBuffer, and then render as necessary.

I manually calculate the transform matrix ahead of time (using an orthographic transform calculated in a non-generic way to reduce multiplications), and the vertex shader looks like:

```
#version 120

varying vec4 _outColor;

uniform vec4 _lBound=vec4(-1.0);
uniform vec4 _uBound=vec4(1.0);
uniform mat4 _xform=mat4(1.0);

attribute vec2 _inPos;
attribute vec4 _inColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position=clamp(_xform*vec4(_inPos, 0.0, 1.0), _lBound, _uBound);
    _outColor=_inColor;
}
```

The `_lBound`, `_uBound`, and `_xform` uniforms are updated once per channel.  So, 32 times per frame.  The clamp is used to limit certain channels to a range of y-coordinates on the screen.

The fragment shader is simply:

```
#version 120

varying vec4 _outColor;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor=_outColor;
}
```

There is other stuff being render to the screen; channel labels, for example, using quads and a texture atlas; but profiling in gDEBugger seems to indicate that the line rendering takes the overwhelming majority of time per frame.

Still, 50,000 lines does not seem like a horrendously large number to me.

So, after all of that, the question is: are there any tricks to speeding up line drawing?  I tried rendering them to the stencil buffer and then clipping a single quad, but that was slower.  I thought about drawing the lines to a texture, the drawing a quad with the texture.  But, that does not seem scalable or even faster due to uploading large textures constantly.  I saw a technique that stores the y values in a single row texture, but that seems more like memory optimization rather than speed optimization.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this question: This is perfectly on-topic on StackOverflow within the opengl tag.

Comment: Don't draw lines or update as often.

Comment: Can you only refresh part of the screen?

Comment: Hmm.  Well, this replaces an old GDI-based system of drawing to a bitmap, shifting the bits, then drawing the next column of data.  If there were a way to do that in OpenGL, it would probably be faster.  Aside from that, probably 90% of the screen changes every frame as the data scrolls.

Comment: @slakr007: Why not rendering to a texture with fbo and simply shift texture, you'll only have to render new sampling value...

Comment: @j-p: That's an interesting idea.  I'll give it a shot.  When I thought about textures, I was thinking about generating a bitmap and uploading it.  I didn't think about using a FBO.

Comment: Argh.  Max texture size is an issue.

Comment: Not sure if this is going to work or not, but I'm going to try experimenting with multiple framebuffers and glBlitFramebuffer().  Basically, copy the rendered data from Framebuffer A to Framebuffer B shifted by one, render the new lines, and output Framebuffer B.

Kind of like the texture idea in a FBO, but gets around the texture size limit.

Comment: Are the lines drawn all in the same view cone or distributed among 3d/2d scene and you move and look around ?

Comment: How about using fixed-function pipeline for the line drawing rather than shader-based pipe line?

Comment: How many OpenGL drawcalls are you issuing to render all the lines? A good way to speed up OpenGL performance is to build the line geometry in a /very/ large vertex buffer and then submit it all in one drawcall to the graphics card. You can easily predict the necessary vertex buffer size, so it shouldn't be an issue. The usual limitation is indeed the number of drawcalls, not actual data bandwidth.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are basically trying to render somethng like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Audacity_1-3-2_screen.PNG), only with 32 tracks? If that is the case, don't draw lines, draw one quad per channel and use the pixel shader.

Comment: @slakr007: why is texture size an issue for fbo rendering? If it's for panning in historic, you could implement paging, and let pages in memory (cpu or gpu (handled by OpenGL internals)) or even save them on disk in a low priority process

Comment: @slakr007: keep in mind that fbo allow multiple color attachments (max num queryable) so your real limit should be `MAX_COLOR_ATTACMENT * MAX_TEX_SIZE`

Comment: @Damon: That's an interesting idea, but wouldn't it require providing the y-values in a 1D texture for the fragment shader?

Comment: Blitting between framebuffers seems to have reduced GPU load by 50% on my machine.  The only downside is the lack of compositing functionality since I am not using textures.

Comment: @j-p: Yeah, I see what you are saying.  It would be possible to write code to use texture tiles to store the data instead of ring buffers.

Comment: @slakr007: Either that, or a buffer texture (if available, has better size constraints), or as an uniform buffer, or something the like.

Comment: @slark007: you may use renderbuffer instead of texture which accept usually bigger dims, queryable (`GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE`)

Comment: @j-p: Yeah, I'm using renderbuffers right now.  I may go the texture route in the future, but basic blitting back and forth seems to work well enough for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, everyone.  I finally settled on blitting between framebuffers backed by renderbuffers.  Works well enough.  Many suggested using textures, and I may go that route in the future if I eventually need to draw behind the data.

Answer (score 2):

Mapping a VBO might slow you down due to the driver might require to sync the GPU with the CPU. A more performant way is to just throw your data onto the GPU, so the CPU and GPU can run more independently.

- Recreate the VBO every time, do create it with STATIC_DRAW
- If you need to map your data, do NOT map as readable (GL_WRITE_ONLY)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just scrolling a line graph (GDI style), just draw the new column on the CPU and use glTexSubImage2D to update a single column in the texture. Draw it as a pair of quads and update the st coordinates to handle scrolling/wrapping.

If you need to update all the lines all the time, use a VBO created with GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW and use glBufferSubData to update the buffer.